# PostgreSQL View Error Handling

Tags: postgresql, view, error-handling

The code given below is a part of a view that I have created. But sometimes it may throw an error saying:

```
division by zero
```

The reason for this error is that **sum(bills.past_arrear)** part may be 0 for some months.

```
SELECT (SELECT revenue_driver.driver_id 
        FROM ccdb.revenue_driver 
        WHERE revenue_driver.driver_desc::text = 'Arrear Collection Efficiency'::text) AS driver_id
       ,bills.org_unit_id::integer AS section_id
       ,date_part('Month'::text, bills.due_date) AS mnth
       ,date_part('Year'::text, bills.due_date) AS yr
       ,ROUND(SUM(COALESCE(bills.arrear_collected,0::numeric))/sum(bills.past_arrear)*100::numeric, 2) AS per_efficiency
       ,now() AS creation_dt
FROM ccdb.bills
WHERE bills.due_date::date >= date_trunc('Month'::text,'now'::text::date::timestamp with time zone)::date
AND bills.due_date::date <= 'now'::text::date
AND (bills.bill_type_group_code::text = ANY (ARRAY['EB'::character varying::text, 'Energy'::character varying::text]))
GROUP BY bills.org_unit_id, date_part('Year'::text, bills.due_date), date_part('Month'::text, bills.due_date);
```

What I want is if **ROUND(SUM(COALESCE(bills.arrear_collected,0::numeric))/sum(bills.past_arrear)*100::numeric, 2)** throws **division by zero** error I want to replace the value with 0.

I have not idea how do handle this error. Kindly someone help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `CASE WHEN` in your select statement like below :-

```
CASE 
    WHEN sum(bills.past_arrear) = 0
    THEN 0
    ELSE ROUND(SUM(COALESCE(bills.arrear_collected, 0::NUMERIC)) / sum(bills.past_arrear) * 10 ‌​0::NUMERIC, 2)
END AS per_efficiency
```